# Как получить число оставшихся запросов?

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Задача следующая: через собственное api следить за расходом запросов и слать sms разработчику, когда заканчивается лимит. Можно ли запросом посмотреть оставшийся лимит?

Comment: *После регистрации не уследил, скинулось часть письма(((

Comment: ... запросов и слать sms разработчику, когда заканчивается лимит. Можно ли запросом посмотреть оставшийся лимит?

Comment: Можно ли получить оставшийся лимит запросов к геокодеру и если да, то как?

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и укажите все нужные параметры в нем

Answer (score 1):

Получить информацию о запросах можно через [API Кабинета разработчика](https://yandex.ru/dev/developer-help/doc/api/auth.html). Обращаться к API Кабинета Разработчика можно только с соответствующим ключом API. Чтобы получить ключ:

1. Перейдите по ссылке https://developer.tech.yandex.ru.
2. Нажмите кнопку **Подключить API**.
3. В открывшемся окне выберите **API Кабинета Разработчика**.

Чтобы посмотреть параметры лимита запросов к API сервисов, используйте HTTP-запрос с методом GET:

```
GET /projects/<project_id>/services/<service_id>/limits
Host:  api-developer.tech.yandex.net
X-Auth-Key:  <ваш API-ключ>
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)